# Compiling multiple .java files and running one that relies on user args

Tags: java

I have two `.java` files. I want to run `ClassB.java` with some user args. however it relies on compiling `ClassA` so I can run the `hello()` method from `main()`

Lets say they are both in the same `src` directory and I have a `.jar` I want to include in my classpath when running `java`.

The following works:

```
javac -cp lib/*.jar src/*.java
```

However when trying to run (with the same classpath):
`java -cp lib/*.jar src/ClassB`

I receive `Could not find or load main class ClassB`

```
lib
 |---file.jar
src
 |---ClassA.java
 |---ClassB.java
```

ClassA.java

```
public class ClassA {
        String item;

        public ClassA(String i) {
                item = i;
        }

        public void hello() {
                System.out.printf("Hello %s from Class A!\n", item);
        }
}
```

ClassB.java

```
public class ClassB {
        String item;

        public ClassB(String i) {
                item = i;
        }

        public void hello() {
                System.out.printf("Hello %s from Class B!\n", item);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                ClassB cb = new ClassB(args[0]);
                ClassA ca = new ClassA(args[1]);

                cb.hello();
                ca.hello();
        }
}
```

Comment: VTC as typo(s). `ClassB cb = new ClassB(args[0]);` and `ClassA ca = new ClassA(args[1]);`

Comment: Ok. But what's the problem now? It works fine with those changes here. You are *compiling* your java files, right? You should if not.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am receiving ```error: cannot find symbol``` for ```ClassA```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Compile the code using the following command -- `javac ClassA.java ClassB.java`.

   - `ClassA.class` and `ClassB.class` should be in the same directory. If they are not, lmk and I can change the answer.
2. Run the code using the following command -- `java ClassB`. Don't put a `.java` at the end, just put `ClassB`.

That should work. Lmk if it does not.

**EDIT** -- It appears OP edited their question. I haven't updated my answer to match the updated question, but I can if anyone feels that I should.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This does make sense. I believe I forgot to include in my question that I want to be able to include a ```classpath``` to a ```.jar``` file when running my ```ClassB```, but I receive the following issue when trying to include a ```.jar``` in the ```classpath``` 

```java -cp lib/*.jar src/ClassB```

```error: Could not find or load main class src.ClassB```.  Or even if I cd into ```src``` and run ```java -cp ../lib/*.jar ClassB``` I receive the same error. I totally forgot to ask this in my question. Sorry.

Comment: Nevermind. I think I figured it out. It was a zsh glob error.. Ugh! Thanks anyways, your answer worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out @Coldchain9 lmk if you need anything else